# how to fix "oh-my-zsh plugin 'docker,' not found"

Tags: oh-my-zsh

When I start [omzsh](/questions/tagged/omzsh) I get this :

```
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'docker,' not found
```

my `.zshrc` looks like this :

```
plugins=(
  docker,
  docker-compose,
  git
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's confusing, either write :

```
plugins=(
  docker
  docker-compose
  git
)
```

or

```
plugins=(docker docker-compose git)
```

**but not**

```
plugins=(
  docker,
  docker-compose,
  git
)
```

or

```
plugins=(docker, docker-compose, git)
```

The reason is that `,` is a valid character for a file. You could have a plugin called `docker,` or even one called `,`.

Comment: actually it should not have the comma either way. But that made me see my error :)

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know that, I knew it could help someone so I created this self-answered question. You can upvote the question and answer if it helped.